# Wrap content not working for dialog

Tags: java, android, listview, dialog

My goal is to create a dialog that wraps its content height as shown in the image below.

[image]

My problem is that my dialog wants to match its parent as shown in the image below. The height should stop at the item "asdf" and this white space below "asdf" should not exist.

[image]

This is my code for the later:

```
private void showPopupEventTest(final String Cardid) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_event);
        SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLt = (SwipeRefreshLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLt);
        ListView lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Contacts_list_view);
        SearchView SearchET = (SearchView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.SearchET);
        LinearLayout layoutLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.layoutLinearLayout);
        EventAdaptor myAdapter = new EventAdaptor(getContext(), ArrayList_EventObject);
        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        dialog.show();

    }
```

And this is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layoutLinearLayout"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/SearchET"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/Contacts_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the code of the dialog's layout file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is in your xml layout. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layoutLinearLayout"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/SearchET"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false" />

    <!--<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLt"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/Contacts_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!--</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>-->

</LinearLayout>
```

**Explanation:**
The problem was the **SwipeRefreshLayout**. I commented it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Window window = customDialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
customDialog.show();
```

Comment: this is not working. I already tried this in the question. Even if I add windw.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) it gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for you

Use **RecyclerView** instead of **ListView**

**OR**

use below code after setting the adapter.

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre - condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: Its not working. see the result: [link](https://scontent.fmru1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/20667977_164129360813060_421894345_n.png?oh=7901ef5789be95ce9d069c822ff63c58&oe=5987E563)

Comment: actually it works for you. Just make its gravity top